# Lag Function vs Next Function in Quantmod / R

Tags: r, lag, lead

The Lag function in quantmod can accept a vector for its "k" periods to lag (and output a matrix or array), but I can find no corresponding way to accomplish such through a forward-looking function - like Next() or lead().

For example,

```
    variable <- runif(5,1,30)
    my.k <- c(2, 3)
    Lag(variable, my.k)
    
returns:
            Lag.2    Lag.3
    [1,]       NA       NA
    [2,]       NA       NA
    [3,] 18.71971       NA
    [4,] 10.98429 18.71971
    [5,] 17.19299 10.98429
```

However, the reciprocal to quantmod's Lag command, i.e., the Next() command, returns the following:

```
   > variable <- runif(5,1,30)
   > my.k <- c(2, 3)
   > Next(variable, my.k)
   Error in Next.numeric(variable, my.k) : k must be a non-negative integer
```

I've tried including as.integer(my.k), but get the same error.  I've also reviewed the help notes through both ?Lag and ?Next.

I began by trying the lag() and lead() functions from the dplyr package - but they both require a "Positive integer of length 1" for "the number of positions to lead or lag by", and provide the following error when trying to include my.k in their respective arguments for n:

```
Error: `n` must be a nonnegative integer scalar, not a double vector of length 2.
```

QUESTION: How can I use my.k (my created vector) in some forward looking function - like Next() or lead() - the same way that i am able to use it in the quantmod Lag function?  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Thank you both for your Answers.  I like the simplicity of using 'flag()' from the collapse package. From a function development perspective, is there a good reason why 'Next()" would not remain consistent with 'Lag()' in terms of being vectorized?  Or why neither 'lead()' nor 'lag()' in dplyr  would offer the flexibility of being vectorized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lag.zoo` in the zoo package and `flag` in the collapse package both support forward and backward vectorized lags.  Either can create all the `my.k` lags in one line of code without iterating.

The first example below converts `variable` to zoo class and then performs the lag using `lag.zoo`.  zoo objects typically do not need padding but if this is intended for use within a data frame which can't handle that we add `na.pad = TRUE`. Then optionally convert back to plain numeric using `coredata` .  Note that dplyr clobbers the generic `lag` function in R so either do not load dplyr, load it using `library(dplyr, exclude = c("lag", "filter"))` or use `stats::lag` to force use of the `lag` generic in base R which in turn will dispatch `lag.zoo`.  If `my.k` has names, they don't in the question, those names will be used to name the output columns.

The second example below uses `flag` in the collapse package.

Note that base R's `lag` is defined such that a series resulting from a positive lag starts earlier. `lag.zoo` is consistent with that convention.  On the other hand in collapse a positive lag means the series starts later.  Thus to refer to past values the series starts later so use negative lags with `lag.zoo` and positive lags with `flag`.  *To pull values backward from the future use the negative of those lags in both cases.*

The code in the question is not reproducible since it uses random numbers without setting the seed so we set the seed as shown in the Note at the end to produce the example input.

### lag.zoo

```
library(zoo)
coredata(stats::lag(as.zoo(variable), -my.k, na.pad = TRUE))
##          lag-2     lag-3
## [1,]        NA        NA
## [2,]        NA        NA
## [3,]  9.339748        NA
## [4,] 23.860849  9.339748
## [5,] 12.860331 23.860849

coredata(stats::lag(as.zoo(variable), my.k, na.pad = TRUE))
##          lag2     lag3
## [1,] 12.86033 26.60750
## [2,] 26.60750 28.27355
## [3,] 28.27355       NA
## [4,]       NA       NA
## [5,]       NA       NA
```

### flag

```
library(collapse)
flag(variable, my.k)
##             L2        L3
## [1,]        NA        NA
## [2,]        NA        NA
## [3,]  9.339748        NA
## [4,] 23.860849  9.339748
## [5,] 12.860331 23.860849
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "matrix"

flag(variable, -my.k)
##            F2       F3
## [1,] 12.86033 26.60750
## [2,] 26.60750 28.27355
## [3,] 28.27355       NA
## [4,]       NA       NA
## [5,]       NA       NA
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "matrix"
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form (using `set.seed`):

```
set.seed(123)

variable <- runif(5,1,30); variable
## [1]  9.339748 23.860849 12.860331 26.607505 28.273551

my.k <- c(2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `next()` is not vectorized. Here is a tidyverse approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

variable <- tibble(values = runif(5,1,30))
my.k <- c(2, 3)

variable
#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>   values
#>    <dbl>
#> 1   9.34
#> 2  23.9 
#> 3  12.9 
#> 4  26.6 
#> 5  28.3

#tidyverse easy way
mutate(variable, lead_1 = lead(values, 2),
       lead_2 = lead(values, 3))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   values lead_1 lead_2
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1   9.34   12.9   26.6
#> 2  23.9    26.6   28.3
#> 3  12.9    28.3   NA  
#> 4  26.6    NA     NA  
#> 5  28.3    NA     NA

#tidyverse when my.k is big
my.k %>% map(~ transmute(variable, lead = dplyr::lead(values, .x))) %>%
    map2_dfc(my.k, ~set_names(.x, paste0('lead_', as.character(.y))))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   lead_2 lead_3
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1   12.9   26.6
#> 2   26.6   28.3
#> 3   28.3   NA  
#> 4   NA     NA  
#> 5   NA     NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>